# How to send mail if TO address is blank in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to send mail with **CC** address and without **TO** address.

**My code is below.**

```
$mail_param['msg'] = "demo";
$mail_param['link'] = "xyz.com";
$email = '';
$name = "demo user";
$cc = 'abc@gmail.com';

Mail::send('view_template', $mail_param, function ($message) use ($email, $name, $cc) {
    if ($cc != '') {
        $message->to($email, $name)->bcc($cc)->subject('Test Mail');
    } elseif ($email != '') {
        $message->to($email, $name)->subject('Test Mail');
    }
});
```

**I am trying above code and get the below error.**

> local.ERROR: Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

Comment: Every mail has any `TO`. It can be your `noreply@...` or whatever.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Maybe you are of the impression that you can only have a single To address and in your case you do not have a primary receiver but multiple equal receivers? Just put all their emails in the to field.

However, AFAIK, plenty of mail server accepts no To and multiple CCs, so, while this may be against the standard it **is** widely supported.

Comment: i have one condition if TO address is blank even so mail send CC address. and if TO address is not blank then mail send TO address and CC.

Comment: i am trying send mail without TO address and with CC address in codeigniter and working perfect but while i am try with laravel so get the error.

Comment: You must set the "to" field.  There is no way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You Can try with array arguments.***

```
$mail_param['msg'] = "demo";
$mail_param['link'] = "xyz.com";
$email = array();
$name = "demo user";
$cc = array('abc@gmail.com');

Mail::send('view_template', $mail_param, function ($message) use ($email, $name, $cc) 
{
   if (!empty($cc)) {
     $message->to($email, $name)->bcc($cc)->subject('Test Mail');
   } elseif (!empty($email)) {
     $message->to($email, $name)->subject('Test Mail');
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you kanji taviya... This is helpfull.